# importing a statement into mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't find and error, when I try to execute:

```
create database android_api 
use android_api 
    create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

I get and error " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

```
use android_api 

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increme' at line 3"
```

Comment: These are basically 3 statements you try to execute at once. Separate them with `;`

Comment: You may be missing some `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just separate your code with ';'

```
create database android_api;
use android_api;
    create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't do it.

Do those processes in 3 different queries.